# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' Making leaderboard using json and discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py, bots

I am fairly new here so I apologise if this post is not up to your standards.

To summarise the problem, I am using Json and Discord.py to create a level leader-board.
I seem to not be able to sort the values in the json database as they are dictionary values, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshots of code and errors:

[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnypf.png)

[Json database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbTF5.png)

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bb3Rn.png)

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, _not_ screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Get the values you want from the dictionary as a tuple, and use that as the key.

```
sorted(users.items(), key = lambda item: (item[1]['level'], item[1]['currency'], item[1]['experience'], reverse=True)
```